# Why can't typescript recognize the type of a parent through its child?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typing

Let's take a look at the next example:

```js
type A_Number = {
    type:  'NUMBER'
    numberValue: number
}

type A_String = {
    type: 'STRING',
    stringValue: string
}

type B_Number = {
    a: A_Number;
    numberData: number;
}

type B_String = {
    a: A_String;
    stringData: string;
}

type A = A_Number | A_String
type B = B_Number | B_String

function test_A_NUMBER(a: A_Number) {}
function test_B_NUMBER(b: B_Number) {}

function test_B(b: B) {
    if (b.a.type === 'NUMBER') {
        test_A_NUMBER(b.a) // TS correctly recognizes that b.a is A_Number
        test_B_NUMBER(b)   // but it can't recognize that b is B_Number (I have typing error here :()
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgg+gOQK4FsBGEBOUC8UDeAUFCVKJAFwkDkCAqgLIBCAogErXGkB2qGmANQCGAGyQQqvdFkIBfQoXLR4AZWCYAltwDmuAlxJKq1FQBU2ASQQBxagBoDUAM7qt24WInPXOuQqVQTIh8WHpEpFBCVPDI0pgA3I5S-AAiQsBRUMlYifKK4NBBapo6YY6Zqj7aiREuJdppGVR1brn+BbB6MSHYAD6wcMVu+ZCBekGx-FD9RVUKAGZI3ADGwBoA9txkEC5wMYysbAAUQhXBcQCUBPKLK2ub27sTB+xHaGhUEz1X+Hm3qxstsAdsA4Ew3p8fo4NPMoG8AHRCeEBHCoqC0F4cKERCLA3b7ZivNCIq4AelJUGW60wmAgqxEICgtKp2m4GgAXjsyAALdJQYlCKAaJwDSYyHGkPGg56E45oK4kcmUoTcajAJl09asjnQYC89VoIUir5xRzyeRAA) is the working example of the code.

Does anybody know why `typescript` can't recognize the specific type of the variable `b`? It looks like it has everything it needs to do it (it knows that `b is B` and it knows that `b.a is A_Number`).

Comment: it recognizes that b.a is A_Number because you check its type in if statement,from that point onwards TS knows that it must be a number and not a string whereas with b, it could be either a number or a string and therefore can't guarantee your type at compile

Comment: @JorgeGuerreiro Thank you for your reply! But, how `b` could be a string if `b.a` is a number? The only possible type for `b` is number in this case. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't seem to be able to infer the correct type for the parent object `b` based on the type of the `b.a` (bottom-up approach). Not really sure if this is a limitation or expected behavior though.

Having said that, instead of checking for `b.a.type === 'NUMBER'`, I'd suggest we can check for the presence of `numberData` in the `b` to reach the same conclusion. With this top-down approach, TS seems to infer the type of `b`, and the type of `b.a` both correctly:

```
function test_B(b: B) {
    if ('numberData' in b) {
        test_A_NUMBER(b.a) // correctly recognizes that b.a is A_Number
        test_B_NUMBER(b)   // now correctly recognizes that b is B_Number
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NV3pMm) with the above change

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's a good solution, but the problem with such approach is that both `B_String` and `B_Number` could have the same list of properties (just with different types). For example both `numberData` and `stringData` could be just named `data`. Then it's impossible to determine the type based on property existence.

Comment: fair enough, I agree